# JSON Data To Array in Flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter

The below code is decoding the Json Data for which the console output is also shown and the json data is also shown.
I am able to decode the data successfully as per the console output.
I want the decoded json data to be stored in an array so that I can store it in firestore document as an array.

How should I do that?
I know how to store data in firestore database, all I need to store the json data in an array.
Please guide me

**CODE**

```
 var parsedData = json.decode(state.successResponse);
                List members = parsedData['members'];
                 members.forEach((member){
               
                  String name1 = member['firstName'];
                 print(name1);
       });
```

**JSON DATA**

```
flutter: {
    "members": [
        {
            "firstName": "Michael"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jennifer"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Lisa"
        }
    ]
}
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
flutter:Michael
flutter:Jennifer
flutter:Lisa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER 2.0**

If the case is to store the data into the array, then we need to have a `List<String>` which will store the `firstname` param. **You can then use `_firstNames` list to be passed to your firestore**

```
    // This will store the name from the data
    List<String> _firstNames = [];
    var parsedData = json.decode(state.successResponse);
    List members = parsedData['members'];
    members.forEach((member){
         // simply add it to the list the data
         _firstNames.add(member['firstName']);
    });

    // print it to check, whether you have got it or not, 
    // outside the loop
    print(_firstNames);
```

I will give out demo as per your data set only in this code example

```
  List<String> _firstNames = [];
  Map _membersData = {
    "members": [
        {
            "firstName": "Michael"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jennifer"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Lisa"
        }
    ]
  };
  
  _membersData["members"].forEach((data){
    _firstNames.add(data["firstName"]);
  });
  print(_firstNames);

  // OUTPUT will be [Michael, Jennifer, Lisa]
```

Try it and let me know

Comment: Alok, I need to store the data in firestore database, the output you shared I can already generate that. In firestore database document I need to store multiple fields of same kind just like we refer array in java or swift or any language, I need to convert the `firstName ` output to array so that I can save that in firestore database. I hope you have idea of firestore database.

Comment: Can you show me how your output should look like, don't code, just show? I will help you out on that @JohnnyWarner. Just this favor is required from your side.

Comment: I the data `JsonData` and `Console Output` I shared, are the types of outputs I am I able to generate. I need to convert that in to an array of Strings so that I can store it in firestore database

Comment: So the array would be like this: `['Michael', 'Jennifer', 'Lisa']` @JohnnyWarner?

Comment: @JohnnyWarner answer updated, please see, and let me know

Comment: it is getting me different arrays, I want them in a single array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217307/discussion-between-johnny-warner-and-alok).